# read removing special chars in the file contents

Tags: bash

If `xx2.txt` has  any line like

```
c:\test\testing.txt
```

the below code removes "\" and returns `c:testtesting.txt`. Is there any option to retain all the characters in the file while reading it??

```
exec 5<xx2.txt
while IFS= read -u 5 line;
do
until [ "$CONTINUE_EXECUTION" = "Y" -o "$CONTINUE_EXECUTION" = "N" ]; do
  read -p "Please press Y to continue or N to exit: " CONTINUE_EXECUTION done
echo $line
CONTINUE_EXECUTION=""
done
```

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html, scroll down to the section on the `read` command.

Comment: As an aside: your code doesn't exit the `while` loop when the user enters `N`.

Answer (score 2):

The Bash `read` builtin by default performs interpretation of `\` chars., which is unfortunate, because it is rarely useful.<sup>[1]</sup>

`read -r` turns this processing off and is almost always what you want.

Applied to your code: `IFS= read -r -u 5 line`

---

<sup>[1] The purpose of this processing is to support *line continuation*, but the `\` is removed from *any* `\<char>` sequence.</sup>

Comment: but if I use -r instead of -u, it just hangs.

Comment: @RamDontineni I don't think anyone asked you to stop using `-u`: `read -ru 5 line`

Comment: My original requirement was to force the user until he enters Y or N while reading the file. But while it is not prompting for the user input as it was reading the file.                                                                                                       while IFS= read -r line;
do
until [ "$CONTINUE_EXECUTION" = "Y" -o "$CONTINUE_EXECUTION" = "N" ]; do
  read -p "Please press Y to continue or N to exit: " CONTINUE_EXECUTION done
echo $line
CONTINUE_EXECUTION=""
done < xx1.txt

Comment: @RamDontineni: As andlrc points out, you need to _add_ the `-r` option to your existing `read` command - I've updated the answer to make that clearer.

Comment: Thanks A lot andlrc. It worked.